# How can we configure values in dependent angular module from depending module

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules

I have a `CoreModule` (which provides common functionalities like providing customised wrapper service on top of `HttpClient` etc. - as npm package), and `AppModule` (Angular application which installs `CoreModule` as npm package).

`CoreModule` has many things regarding configuration (i.e. `login URL, base URL for REST endpoints`, etc.). So whenever I need to fetch data from the server, I just give `endpoint URL` to the services exposed by `CoreModule` and then it takes care of rest of the things like creating complete request URL, making ajax call, providing response, etc.

Now, is there any way so that I can update (override) the `base URL` (of `CoreModule`) from my `AppModule`?

In Angular 1.x, we used to have `value` recipe. So, we could do like

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$provide', function($provider){
   $provider.decorator('configVarsInCoreModule', ['$delegate', function($delegate){
       // give configParamFromClientApp
       angular.extend($delegate, configParamFromClientApp);
   }]);
}]);
```

Is there any similar (or different) way available in Angular 4+ to achieve similar kind of behaviour?

The thing is, once I update/override the `baseURL` (or any other config variable) from client app, it should be updated for the `CoreModule` as well. So if any other service/component tries to access the variable (even from `CoreModule`), it should read the updated value.

Comment: Well,  did you try `useClass` , `useExisting` ? i am also not sure but i think it might do the trick .

Comment: Yes it is really nice idea. You can provide config class to DI and then use values and functionality (e.g. setBaseUrl) of that class where it is needed.

Comment: will that do the trick even for `CoreModule` along with `AppModule`?

Comment: Core module will provide this class to DI. Then you will inject it where it is needed, so instance must be the same for whole app.

Comment: I am not sure, have to check, coz I think only `AppModule` will get the updated value (the value to be updated is provided by the client app only), `CoreModule` won't as I won't be providing that class at `CoreModule` level.